# Is 'a^b' a valid Regular Expression in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle11g, regexp-like

Is 'a^b'  a valid Regular Expression in oracle sql? If yes what are the strings(give some examples) that could qualify.

```
select name from employees where regexp_like(name,'a^b');
```

Comment: @Tushar nope, I tried it doesn't qualify the  string "a^b"

Comment: @Tushar FYI - You would have to escape it like this: `\^` to take away the special meaning of the anchor to the start of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's valid, but it will never match anything.  `^` is a zero-width assertion that matches the beginning of the string or right after a newline. But it can't match `a\nb` ( `a`-newline-`b`) because there's nothing in the regex to match the newline itself.  So `a^b` is syntactically valid, but it's nonsense.

Comment: just incase can you give regex for ( a-newline-b)

Comment: Oracle's regex flavor provides no way to do that.  It seems you have to use whatever mechanism is available to insert an actual newline into the regex string.  In PL/SQL, from what I can gather, that's something like `'a' || CHR (10) 'b'`.

Comment: ... where `regexp_like(name,'a' || CHR(10) || 'b')`